# Toggle Text Value in Span for Password?

Tags: jquery

I am looking to put together a list of passwords (without them being in a text field) and want that password to be marked out until a user clicks to view it.

Basically:

Client Name
Username: oidjdoisjs
Password: ••••••••••

Then when the user clicks or hovers over the password is changes to the text:

Client Name
Username: oidjdoisjs
Password: *doieiowwe*

Any help would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dittodhole/hgrv9/)?

```
<span class="magic" data-password="test">****</span>​
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var $magics = $('.magic');
    $magics.each(function (index, element) {
        var $magic = $(element);
        var password = $magic.data('password');
        $magic.one('click', function () {
            $magic.text(password);
        });
    });​
});
</script>
```

or (without the `$.each`) - and an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/dittodhole/hgrv9/1/):

```
<span class="magic" data-password="test">****</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var $magics = $('.magic');
    $magics.one('click', function () {
        var $magic = $(this);
        var password = $magic.data('password');
        $magic.text(password);
    });
});
</script>
```

*note*: the [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) is on intention - as you do not need to revert back to '*****' the event should only fire once!

*edit*: aahhh ... i just saw the request for `hover` right now - to achieve this, you only need to change the first parameter of `.one` to `'click hover'`

Comment: Is there a benefit to using each() rather than getting the password in the 'click' function? Also - typo on the 'click' line ('on' not 'one').

Comment: @Grim no... that's no typo - since there is no change-back to '****' i only need to do it once. and yes, you could also do that without an each :)

Comment: @Grim happens to my quite often as well :)

Answer (score 3):

another implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/5McS2/2/

```
$('input').on('click.revealPassword',
    function() {
        if (this.value === "") return false;
        this.type = (this.type === "text")? "password" : "text";
   }
)
```

it works on Fx10, Ch17, Sf5.0.4, Op11. Not working on IE<8 (IE9 not tested)

Comment: I tried Fx10, Ch17, Sf5.0.4, Op11. I guess the problem here is IE<9. If we consider this as *progressive enhancement* he could make available this feature on newer IE

Comment: he could - but it would be nice if you include this precious piece of information into your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try HTML:

```
<span class="hiddenPassword"><span style="display:none">thePassword</span>*****</span>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".hiddenPassword").click(function() {
    var pw = $(this).children("span").text();
    $(this).text(pw);
});
```

Comment: very ... very ... bad solution ... :) what if the id collides with another id?? maybe you should use the new `data-`-attribute

Comment: Works, but duplicate ID's are not allowed in a valid HTML document. If two users have the same password, your document will be invalid.

Comment: The data-* is only valid in HTML5. I'll change it for the validity police =]

Comment: @Grim i know ... just for the records :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it works in all browsers:

```
<input type="password" id="pw" />
```

JS:

```
var $pw = $("#pw");
$pw.focus(function() {
    $pw.get(0).type = "text";
});
$pw.blur(function() {
    $pw.get(0).type = "password";   
});
```

See live example: http://jsfiddle.net/pdDxZ/

Comment: I tried that once and many browsers will throw an error when you are trying to change password to a text

Answer (score 0):

try this:

jQuery prior 1.7

```
function textify(ref) {
    var prop = $(ref).prop('type') == 'text' ? 'password': 'text';
    $(ref).prop('type', prop);
}
$('input[type="password"]#password').click(function() {
    textify(this);
}).hover(function() {
    textify(this);
},
function() {
    textify(this);
});
```

jquery 1.7.*

```
function textify(ref) {
    var prop = $(ref).prop('type') == 'text' ? 'password': 'text';
    $(ref).prop('type', prop);
}
$('input[type="password"]#password').on('click hover',
function(e) {
    textify(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While it isn't possible to change an input field from type `text` to `password`, you can replace it with another element and change the type there:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pass = $('#pass');
    pass.click(function() {
        if (pass.attr('type') == 'password') {
            pass.replaceWith('<input id="pass" name="pass" type="text" value="' + pass.val() + '" />');
        }
    });
});​
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kB9rA/1/